# How to call NotifyDataSetChanged() outside of custom adapter class?

Tags: android, listview

I have an ArrayList in an activity that populates a listView using a custom adapter class. The custom adapter class code is within the activity and the database adapter code is in the same activity outside of the custom adapter class. I can't seem to figure out how to call NotifyDataSetChanged() from outside the custom adapter class in the activity once the database is updated to refresh the listView. I know I need to create references somehow in the activity so I can call NotifyDataSetChanged() on the custom listView adapter class but after several days this has still eluded me. Believe me I have read and tried every solution on here and I'm still unable to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   public class getServers extends Activity {   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.server_list); 


//ServerList ArrayList
        ArrayList<ServerList> Items = new ArrayList<ServerList>();                            


        //Create the listview
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(new ServerItemAdapter(this, R.layout.server_list_item, Items));

        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);        


//Updates the server status to 0 (Forget)
        public void updateServerStatus(Integer pos) {       
        String ID = gstrServerMacs[pos];        

        //Open the connection to the database adapter   
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 
        db.open();
        //Do the update
        Cursor c = db.updateStatus(ID); 
        c.moveToFirst(); 
        db.close();
        c.close(); 
//Fill the arrays with the updated data from th db                          
        getServerList();

        **I NEED TO CALL NotifyDataSetChanged() HERE!!!**

        }   

//LISTVIEW CLASS START/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class ServerItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ServerList> {
        private ArrayList<ServerList> Items;
        //private String[] values;  

        public ServerItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ServerList> Items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, Items);          
            this.Items = Items;
        }

        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;       
            if (v == null) {        
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.server_list_item, parent, false);
            }

//Array adapter
        public class ServerList {       
            public String ServerName;
            public String ServerMAC;
            public String ServerIP; 

            public ServerList(String ServerName, String ServerMAC, String ServerIP) {
                this.ServerName = ServerName;
                this.ServerMAC = ServerMAC;
                this.ServerIP = ServerIP;       
            }
        }
```

Comment: have u tried calling it from the instance of the custom adapter?

Comment: I need to call it from the method that updates the database which is located outside of the custom adapter class.

Comment: can u post your code?

Comment: Yeah I'll try to post the important parts.

Comment: declare the ServerItemAdapter globally in the Activity and 

     `public void updateServerStatus(Integer pos , ServerItemAdapter     adapter) {       
        String ID = gstrServerMacs[pos];        

        //Open the connection to the database adapter   
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 
        db.open();
        //Do the update
        Cursor c = db.updateStatus(ID); 
        c.moveToFirst(); 
        db.close();
        c.close(); 
//Fill the arrays with the updated data from th db                          
        getServerList(); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}`

Comment: have you tried **listview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChange()** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
listView.setAdapter(new ServerItemAdapter(this, R.layout.server_list_item, Items));
```

to

```
public class getServers extends Activity {   
   ServerItemAdapter ad = null;
   ...... other codes here
```

then in your onCreate

```
ad = new ServerItemAdapter(this, R.layout.server_list_item, Items))
listView.setAdapter(ad);
```

and you can call

```
ad.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an example. I tried it and I got this error:
08-08 01:11:53.445: E/AndroidRuntime(15649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 01:11:53.445: E/AndroidRuntime(15649): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
08-08 01:11:53.445: E/AndroidRuntime(15649):

Comment: check if data is returned from the database or not.... try to debug getServerList() method..

Comment: Oh right... I just removed data from the database and then tried to update the list with nothing. That's probably it.

Comment: I still need to debug this error but I think the NotifyDataSetChanged() problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
YourAdapterName.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or

```
YourAdapterName adapter=new YourAdapterName(this, R.layout.list_item, arrItem)
YourListView.setAdapter(YourAdapterName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the activity that creates the adapter then you can add a method to that activity that calls notify adapter and pass the acticity to the class that adds to your the db. Other methods include using broadcast and setting up a local broadcast listener in the activity that maintains the custom adapter. Singletons are also an option but they are collected by the garbage collector so be careful cause you can waste memory and in android dev that is a precious reasource.

Instead of using:

```
listView.setAdapter(new ServerItemAdapter(this, R.layout.server_list_item, Items));
```

Have a copy of serverItemAdapter as a feild in the activity and set it like this in onCreate:

```
this.serverItemAdapter = new ServerItemAdapter(this, R.layout.server_list_item, Items));
listView.setAdapter(serverItemAdapter);
```

Comment: Could you take a look at the small part of my code that I just posted and maybe leave an example of how I would do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like below

```
//Create the listview
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

ServerItemAdapter adapter=new ServerItemAdapter(this, R.layout.server_list_item, Items)

listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

then call like below

```
getServerList();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

Use this in your fragment and then call notifydatasetchanged using adapter's object which you used to create the adapter

Answer (score 0):

Even though Michael Shrestha's solution works perfectly, I'm just going to add that you don't need to keep the reference to the ServerItemAdapter object.

If you are accessing it from outside scope, you can get it from the ListView object and cast it so you can call notifyDataSetChanged(). Like so:

```
ServerItemAdapter listAdapter = (ServerItemAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

With this method, you can save some memory.

Again, just leaving it here for future reference.